# How can execute some operations only if a specific JButton is clicked? Some doubts trying to use getSource()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I am pretty new in Java **Swing** development and I have some doubts about how handle the following situation.

I have a custo **LoginFrame** class that extends a classic Swing **JFrame** class.

In my class I have a **JButton** and a method that will be perform when my button is clicked, something like this:

```
JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Button LogIn cliccked");
    System.out.println("SOURCE: " + e.getSource());

    if(e.getSource() == "loginButton"){
        System.out.println("BLABLABLA");
         String name = userNameTextField.getText();
         char[] pass = pswdTextField.getPassword();
         // your remaining operation...
    }
```

The method work and, in the Eclipse console, print the message **"Button LogIn cliccked"**  but I think that if I had more JButton objects this message will always print...so I am trying to use the **getSource** method, but in the used way seems not work beause can't recognize "loginButton" ass the source of the clicked button.

I have also try to print my souce by this line:

```
System.out.println("SOURCE: " + e.getSource());
```

and the output is:

```
SOURCE: javax.swing.JButton[,6,152,95x30,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@1167e3a5,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Login,defaultCapable=true]
```

What can I do to execute something only if the specific **loginButton** is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this  `if(e.getSource() == "loginButton")` to  `if(e.getSource() == loginButton)`. Because your button object never equal to a String.

If you want compare with your button label, Try this..

```
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Login")){

}
```

Or simply you can use like this..

```
    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // your action.

        }
    });
```